# homogeneous coordinate rings of isomorphic projective varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

As i understand, there are two notions of "equivalence" of projective varieties. The first is projective equivalence, under which projective varieties $X,Y$ of $\mathbb{P}^n(k)$ are mapped to
each other by an invertible $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix. In that case 
their corresponding homogeneous coordinate rings are isomorphic as 
$k$-algebras. The second notion is weaker and is the notion of the two
varieties being isomorphic, under which a biregular morphism exists
between $X,Y$.

**Question:** What can we say about the homogeneous coordinate rings
of two isomorphic projective varieties?

Of course, the two rings will must have the same Krull dimension,
but can we say anything else?